# What is the integral of square root of $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\sec x$ and $\text{cosec } x$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I have solved integral of square root of $\tan x$, $\cot x$, but I could not solve these questions. I know first we put $\tan x=t(\textrm{any variable})$ and solve further.

Comment: $\sqrt{\sin x}=\sqrt{\tan x*\cos x}=\sqrt{\tan x}*\sqrt{\cos x}$ -- did you try integrating by parts and using your answer for $\sqrt{\tan x}$?

Comment: yes i tried that method ,but i am not able to get answer.

Comment: i m able to solve square root of tan(x),but i m not able to solve square root of cos(x)

Comment: This question is terrible: it is too broad in its focus, and also does not show any work. If this question were posted today, it would have been closed in an hour.